# Draw a Column of Nodes with a For Loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a 'column' of nodes, something like the following (except I would want all the nodes to be the same dimensions).

[image]

Which I created with the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] (10) {10};
\node[draw, below= 0cm of 10] (9) {9};
\node[draw, below= 0cm of 9] (8) {8};
\node[draw, below= 0cm of 8] (7) {7};
\node[draw, below= 0cm of 7] (6) {6};
\node[draw, below= 0cm of 6] (5) {5};
\node[draw, below= 0cm of 5] (4) {4};
\node[draw, below= 0cm of 4] (3) {3};
\node[draw, below= 0cm of 3] (2) {2};
\node[draw, below= 0cm of 2] (1) {1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] (10) {10};

\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} {
     \node[draw, below= 0cm of 10-\xi+1 ] (\x) {\x};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I get the error:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named 10-1+1 is known.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I should mention, I want to be able to address each node like (10), (9), etc. as this shape is to be part of a larger drawing where this will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,          % <---
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,         % <---
      start chain = A going below  % <---
                    ]
\foreach \x in {10, 9,..., 1}   % <---
{
\node[draw, minimum width=2em, minimum height=3ex, on chain] {\x}; % <---
}
\draw (A-1.east) -- ++ (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

differences between your MWE in my suggestion are marked by `% <---`. Nodes names are `A-1` (which contain number 10) , ... `A-10` (which contain number 1). You can reverse drawing nodes from top to bottom to bottom to top. In this case the number in nodes' contents are equal to number in node label:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
      start chain = A going above
                    ]
\foreach \x in {1, 2,..., 10} 
{
     \node[draw, minimum width=2em, minimum height=3ex, on chain] {\x};
}
\draw (A-10.east) -- ++ (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

above example gives the same result as the first one.

Comment: The drawing looks exactly asI would want, but is there any way to label each node? I'm going to be drawing arrows and such to them

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment - I just need to put \node[draw, minimum width=2em, minimum height=3ex, on chain] (\x) {\x}; and that works. Thank you!

Comment: @gilbereth, yes, it is possible. See edited answer.

Comment: @gilbereth, this happen at any image when it become to tall. You need to define smaller nodes (reduce `minimum height`, `inner sep` and font size.

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue by changing margins (that's why I deleted my comment). Thanks for all your help!